# d3.js horizontal Bar chart issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, d3.js, charts

I am new to d3 library and trying some charts using d3 library. I am able to made horizontal bar chart using d3.js library but I am stuck at some issues .

**Currently I am having trouble as last value in x axis is getting            cropped. I don't want to add right margin in my chart. And I want to show last label with tick on x axis.**

I have highlighted the cropped value in the screenshot below:

[image: Bar chart Screenshot]

**For debugging , refer below code :**

```js
const margin = {
    top: 30,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 10,
    left: 100
};
const width= 1180;
const data = [{
        name: 'A',
        value: 2
    },
    {
        name: 'B',
        value: 20
    },
    {
        name: 'C',
        value: 15
    },
    {
        name: 'D',
        value: 8
    },
    {
        name: 'E',
        value: 1
    }
];
const barHeight = 20;
const yMax = d3.max(data, d => d.value);

const height =
    Math.ceil((data.length + 0.1) * barHeight) + margin.top + margin.bottom;
const x = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, yMax < 10 ? 10 : yMax])
    .range([margin.left, width - margin.right])
    .nice();
const y = d3
    .scaleBand()
    .domain(d3.range(data.length))
    .range([margin.top, height - margin.bottom])
    .padding(0.1);

const format = x.tickFormat(10, data.format);
const svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('viewBox', [0, 0, width, height]);
const xAxis = g =>
    g
    .attr('class', 'chartxAxisText')
    .attr('transform', `translate(0,${margin.top})`)
    .call(d3.axisTop(x))

    .call(g => g.select('.domain').remove());
const yAxis = g =>
    g
    .attr('class', 'chartyAxisText')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left},0)`)
    .call(
        d3
        .axisLeft(y)
        .tickFormat(i => data[i].name)
        .tickSizeOuter(0)
    );

svg
    .append('g')
    .selectAll('rect')
    .data(data)
    .enter().append('rect')
    .attr('x', x(0))
    .attr('y', (d, i) => y(i))
    .attr('width', d => x(d.value) - x(0))
    .attr('height', y.bandwidth())
    .attr('class', 'chartbar')

svg
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'chartbarTextWrap')
    .selectAll('text')
    .data(data)
    .enter().append('text')
    .attr('x', d => x(d.value) - 4)
    .attr('y', (d, i) => y(i) + y.bandwidth() / 2)
    .attr('dy', '0.35em')
    .text(d => format(d.value))
    .attr('class', 'chartbarText');

svg.append('g').call(xAxis);

svg.append('g').call(yAxis);
```

```css
.chartbarTextWrap {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    fill: #fff;
    text-anchor: end;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.chartbar {
    fill: red;
}
.chartxAxisText, .chartyAxisText {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #424242;
}
.chartxAxisText, .chartyAxisText {
   
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #424242;
}
svg {
  width:1180px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<html>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: why not do `const yMax = d3.max(data, d => d.value + 1);`?

Comment: Welcome to stackOverflow. One remark about the question: it would help to know what is the desired behaviour, since there can be many ways to solve this problem. [Guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a small margin at the right of the chart would really be the most straightforward solution.

If you really do not want it, you may align the `x` axis text labels to the right:

```
.chartxAxisText {
    text-anchor: end;
}
```

This is demonstrated in the snipped below.

```js
const margin = {
    top: 30,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 10,
    left: 100
};
const width= 1180;
const data = [{
        name: 'A',
        value: 2
    },
    {
        name: 'B',
        value: 20
    },
    {
        name: 'C',
        value: 15
    },
    {
        name: 'D',
        value: 8
    },
    {
        name: 'E',
        value: 1
    }
];
const barHeight = 20;
const yMax = d3.max(data, d => d.value);

const height =
    Math.ceil((data.length + 0.1) * barHeight) + margin.top + margin.bottom;
const x = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, yMax < 10 ? 10 : yMax])
    .range([margin.left, width - margin.right]);
const y = d3
    .scaleBand()
    .domain(d3.range(data.length))
    .range([margin.top, height - margin.bottom])
    .padding(0.1);

const format = x.tickFormat(10, data.format);
const svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('viewBox', [0, 0, width, height]);
const xAxis = g =>
    g
    .attr('class', 'chartxAxisText')
    .attr('transform', `translate(0,${margin.top})`)
    .call(d3.axisTop(x))

    .call(g => g.select('.domain').remove());
const yAxis = g =>
    g
    .attr('class', 'chartyAxisText')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left},0)`)
    .call(
        d3
        .axisLeft(y)
        .tickFormat(i => data[i].name)
        .tickSizeOuter(0)
    );

svg
    .append('g')
    .selectAll('rect')
    .data(data)
    .enter().append('rect')
    .attr('x', x(0))
    .attr('y', (d, i) => y(i))
    .attr('width', d => x(d.value) - x(0))
    .attr('height', y.bandwidth())
    .attr('class', 'chartbar')

svg
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'chartbarTextWrap')
    .selectAll('text')
    .data(data)
    .enter().append('text')
    .attr('x', d => x(d.value) - 4)
    .attr('y', (d, i) => y(i) + y.bandwidth() / 2)
    .attr('dy', '0.35em')
    .text(d => format(d.value))
    .attr('class', 'chartbarText');

svg.append('g').call(xAxis);

svg.append('g').call(yAxis);
```

```css
.chartbarTextWrap {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    fill: #fff;
    text-anchor: end;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.chartbar {
    fill: red;
}
.chartxAxisText, .chartyAxisText {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #424242;
}
.chartxAxisText {
    text-anchor: end;
}
svg {
  width:1180px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<html>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Another option is to leave all the labels as they currently are, and only align the last one to the left. This can be done also in CSS, with the following rule:

```
.chartxAxisText text:last-child {
    text-anchor: end;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate you solution but if  I used `.chartxAxisText text {
    text-anchor: end;
}` then ticks will not be aligned with x axis label . 
And if I used `.chartxAxisText text:last-child {
    text-anchor: end;
}` then last tick  is still hidden.

Comment: So how would you like the chart to look like?  Please edit the question to make it explicit.

Comment: As by using `.chartxAxisText text:last-child { text-anchor: end; } ` last number i.e 20 is shown , I just want to  show tick also for last label.

Comment: Then a small margin is the solution ‍♂️

Comment: Thanks for your time. If except margin right their is no other solution , then I will use margin right only.